# Why are action function called wrapped inside dispatch in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I was just going through some react-redux code online and basically i came across the following set of code , which is basically a js file full of `ACTIONS` , just to give some context a combination of redux and redux-thunk is being used here:

```
export const init = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: TYPES.SET_LOADING });
  await dispatch(getConfig());
  await dispatch(getGenres());
  dispatch({ type: TYPES.REMOVE_LOADING });
};

// Action Creator to get the config object from the API
export const getConfig = () => async dispatch => {
  const res = await tmdbAPI.get('/configuration');
  dispatch({
    type: TYPES.GET_CONFIG,
    payload: res.data,
  });
};
```

I am a bit confused as to why is `getConfig` function is being wrapped inside a `dispatch` ?

Comment: Probably `getConfig` will fetch some configuration data like api keys, tokens, etc. So before making any other server calls like `init`, they are just updating the store with these configurations values so that it can be stored locally and used globally by the entire application.

Comment: when you use react-redux connect you can have action creators that automatically get their result dispatched: `onClick={props.getConfig}`  getConfig() results in a function that takes dispatch as a parameter and the thunk middleware will execute that function with dispatch and store parameter.

Comment: Thunk is middleware that gives you extra flexibility on how you dispatch actions. Look closely at `init`. It is basically a super-action that is composed of many smaller actions. You can't do something like that without thunk or other middlewares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want, don't wrap that
**like this**

```js
export const init = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: TYPES.SET_LOADING });
  dispatch(await getConfig());
  dispatch({ type: TYPES.REMOVE_LOADING });
};

//this is not using redux-thunk

// Action Creator to get the config object from the API
export const getConfig = async () => {
  const res = await tmdbAPI.get('/configuration');
  return {
    type: TYPES.GET_CONFIG,
    payload: res.data,
  };
};
```

***Important***
but there are so many reasons why wrap the actions by dispatch.

**Here is one example.**

*when you want get multiple data in one action step by step*

```
export const getData = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: DATA_LOADING_START
  });
  try {
    const res = await tmdbAPI.get('/url1');
    dispatch({
      type: DATA1_LOADED,
      payload: res.data,
    });
    const res = await tmdbAPI.get('/url2');
    dispatch({
      type: DATA2_LOADED,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    // handle error
  }
  dispatch({
    type: DATA_LOADING_END
  });
};
//this is using redux-thunk
```

@AlexanderSolonik
**Question:** *Why wrap actions by dispatch?*

because `dispatch()` sends the action result to the reducer.
[image]

Comment: Dragon to summerize my question why not `await getConfig();` why do we have to `await dispatch(getConfig());` ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik, you can do it. I updated the answer.

Comment: Hi Dragon , thanks for you're insightful answer , i am still a bit confused , why do we need dispatch when calling a function , see my comment here https://jsfiddle.net/ahwpzcfk/

Comment: oh ok maybe i get it , in order for `getConfig` to receive dispatch as a argument , we need to do `await dispatch(getConfig());` ? am i right ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik, **about the last question**: yeah, that's it. you make the dispatch asynchronous, so if you want perfect result( SET_LOADING -> getConfig -> getGenres -> REMOVE_LOADING ), you should write the `await` before the dispatch. and answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Redux thunks are just redux actions that can perform side effects. So

```
export const init = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: TYPES.SET_LOADING });
  await dispatch(getConfig());
  await dispatch(getGenres());
  dispatch({ type: TYPES.REMOVE_LOADING });
};
```

Is just an async init function which when called performs the steps in a synchronous manner.

The key is that thunks can dispatch other thunks/actions/etc so the init thunk is just dispatching the `getConfig()` action which is itself async so the next step of the init function won't be performed until the config API call finishes (possibly because some other code depends on it)